# Creating a HashMap for custom object

Tags: java, hashmap

Not to sure if this has been asked or answered but I seem to be having trouble with it.

I have a class (Location) with a constructor that reads a file, based on the name parameter, that has all the information for a location. My thought was that each time a location is travelled too the constructor will read the file and create it on the fly. My problem is that I have a class wide HashMap that seems to be getting overridden once I create a second location.

Start of the Location class

```
public class Location extends Assets{

private String name;
private String desc;
public static HashMap<String, Location> map;
private static HashMap<Direction, String> exits = new HashMap<>();
```

Start of the constructor

```
public Location(String name) {
    super(name);
            
    //loads each location file as they are travelled too
    String filename = "res/" + name + ".txt";
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            
            String[] entry = line.replace(",", "").split("-",2);
            arr.add(entry[1]);                      
        }

        setName(arr.get(0));
        setDesc(arr.get(1));
        
        exits.put(Direction.NORTH, arr.get(2));     
        exits.put(Direction.EAST, arr.get(3));
        exits.put(Direction.SOUTH, arr.get(4));
        exits.put(Direction.WEST, arr.get(5));
```

But as I mentioned above the second location I create completely overwrites the previous locations exit data when called from my very simple map class. The name and description methods still work fine but for whatever reason both locations show the same exit data which I know to be incorrect.

Map class

```
public class Map {

public static HashMap<String, Location> map = new HashMap<>();
    
public static void readMap(String name) 
{
    System.out.println(map.get(name).getName());
    map.get(name).getDesc();
    map.get(name).getExits();   
    System.out.println("");
}

public static String lowerString(String name)
{
    String str = name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    return str;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Location riverbank = new Location("riverbank");
    Location rabbithole = new Location("rabbithole");
    
    map.put("riverbank", riverbank);
    map.put("rabbithole", rabbithole);  
    
    readMap(lowerString("River Bank"));
    readMap(lowerString("Rabbit Hole"));        
}
```

}

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve, but the problem is that you are using the hashmap with 4 keys: Direction.NORTH, Direction.EAST, Direction.SOUTH, Direction.WEST. So every time you load a new location you overwrite all of those keys

Comment: You have one `HashMap` (which really should be an `EnumMap`) with four entries (one for each key, i.e. `Direction`-value `NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`, `WEST`). This map is filled with data in the constrctor. When you call the constructor a second time, what do you think happens with the the data that is already in the map?

Comment: *the second location I create completely overwrites the previous locations exit data* because it's static.

Comment: Thank you all for your insight, I can't believe I didn't realize that. Rookie mistake I suppose.
Side not im going to look into EnumMap. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your exits MAP as static so it will class level and will be common for all objects.

You might know that in case of MAP if tries to put different data in same map with already existing key then it will update the value.

So in your case values related to latest object only will be present in MAP and for every location object it will same.

So either declare exits MAP object as instance variable or change your approach in case you need object level values.